# Does the value change if I change a numpy array to a list and then change the list to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a program like this.

1. First, convert the image file to the numpy array.
2. Switch the converted numpy array to a list.
3. Save the list in the txt file (because if the program stores the numpy array in the txt file as it is, the middle part is entered omitted).
4. Call up the list saved in the txt file and convert the list to a numpy array.
5. Save the numpy array as a picture.

So I wrote the code and executed it, but the result came out as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0aoK.jpg)

↑This is original image file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lZB9.png)

↑This is converted image file

So, to find a problem, I wrote the code as follows.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

imgArr = cv.imread("salmon.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
s = np.array(imgArr).tolist()
t = np.array(s)
img1 = Image.fromarray(t, "RGB")
img2 = Image.fromarray(imgArr, "RGB")
img1.save("ex.png")
img2.save("ex2.png")
```

The image(ex.png) is broken when the program draws an image file with a converted numpy array from the list, but the numpy array that does not switch to the list has a good picture(ex2.png).

I think they're both in the same numpy array, but why are they creating image files with different results?

Comment: If you read images with OpenCV and write them unmodified with PIL, you will find the red and blue channels are swapped. Either read and write with the same library, or re-order your channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are changing the data from `numpy array` to `list`, datatype is changing from `uint8` to `uint32`. So when you are converting the `list` back to `numpy array` you need to specify the `datatype` as `uint8`.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

imgArr = cv.imread("salmon.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

s = np.asarray(imgArr).tolist()
t = np.array(s, dtype="uint8")
img1 = Image.fromarray(imgArr, "RGB")
img2 = Image.fromarray(t, "RGB")
img1.save("ex.png")
img2.save("ex2.png")
```